# elixir: order a list of numbers without built-in sort function

Tags: list, sorting, elixir, elixir-iex

If I have a list that varies in length each time and I want to sort it from lowest to highest, how would I do that?

If I have: `[-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, 0.7, -6, 23, 67]`

I want: `[-23, -6, -5, 0, 0.7, 5, 23, 23, 67]`

I tried to use a for loop to iterate the list and create a new list to receive the numbers but doesn't look like it's gonna work. maybe i can use `Enum` function instead, but i'm really without ideas on this one.

Comment: In the subject, you said "without built-in sort function", do you mean you don't want to use Enum.sort?

Comment: Exactly, i can't use it

Comment: Why not? It is available on every Elixir system. Are you doing an exercise? Sorting is a fundamental computer science problem, so if you must write your own algorithm, first you have to pick which one. Elixir being immutable language, the options are different than for mutable languages (quick-sort doesn't work well in Elixir, for example). `Enum.sort` uses merge sort.

Comment: Yeah, that's an exercise for learning elixir and computer science together

Comment: Do you want somebody to write the sorting algorithm for you? Then you won't learn anything, and you may as well look at the existing implementations in that case.

Comment: I'm looking for somewhere to start, i couldn't find some implemetation that did'nt use the Enum.sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use `Enum.sort`, you have to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Elixir is an immutable language, so popular algorithms that require in-place operations like [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) do not work well in Elixir. Here is an implementation of [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort):

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def merge_sort([]), do: []
  def merge_sort([_] = list), do: list

  def merge_sort(list) when is_list(list) do
    len = length(list)
    {a, b} = Enum.split(list, div(len, 2))
    a = merge_sort(a)
    b = merge_sort(b)
    merge(a, b, [])
  end

  defp merge([], b, acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc) ++ b
  defp merge(a, [], acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc) ++ a

  defp merge([a_head | a_tail] = a, [b_head | b_tail] = b, acc) do
    if a_head <= b_head do
      merge(a_tail, b, [a_head | acc])
    else
      merge(a, b_tail, [b_head | acc])
    end
  end
end
```

Running:

```elixir
iex> Example.merge_sort([-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, 0.7, -6, 23, 67])
[-23, -6, -5, 0, 0.7, 5, 23, 23, 67]
```

---

Just for fun, here is `reverse` and `split`, if you don't want to use `Enum` at all:

```elixir
defp reverse(list), do: reverse(list, [])
defp reverse([], acc), do: acc
defp reverse([h | t], acc), do: reverse(t, [h | acc])

defp split(list, n), do: split(list, [], n)
defp split(a, b, 0), do: {reverse(b), a}
defp split([h | a], b, n), do: split(a, [h | b], n - 1)
```

<sup>We can even simplify `{reverse(b), a}`, to `{b, a}` in this case, because there's no need to preserve the item order when splitting, since the result gets sorted anyway.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Below is an extremely inefficient but probably the simplest solution with [`Enum.split_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_while/2)

```elixir
Enum.reduce(list, [], fn x, acc ->
  {pre, post} = Enum.split_while(acc, & &1 < x)
  pre ++ [x] ++ post
end)
```

It looks like homework, so there is a huge room for improvement. For the reference, one might pick up any of existing [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) and implement any of them.

Comment: That's really neat @Aleksei_Matiushkin But if `Enum.sort` is out-of-bounds then the ingenious `Enum.split_while` would likely be too.! In any case, please can you explain the role of the two `&`s as you second argument.

Comment: It is a function capture.